# BotFramework Web Chat with existing chat box

Tags: c#, websocket, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to understand how to integrate BotFramework (C#) with an existing application without the use of Azure and using DirectLine, but everything I have seen so far requires an Azure subscription. I have looked at [ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but not sure if that is reliable for a production environment. I have also been digging around the source code repositories of [BotFramework-Emulator](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator) and [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), but haven't found good information that relates to my use case.

- If we have an existing "chat box", that has already been styled and has some basic commands that a user can enter, how could I reuse that chat box, but just implement the BotFramework routing? The idea being it is our standard chat box, but when the user types a command like `/todo` it would start a new bot conversation.
- Without Azure, how would we generate a DirectLine token to access our C# WebAPI BotFramework Chatbot? I tried just opening a WebSocket in devtools to try and send messages, but wasn't successful

Sure, it is possible to just to plain REST routing, but would ideally like to use WebSocket to send/receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the Azure Bot Service is a required component of using the Microsoft Bot Framework as it serves as the connector (via the supported channels - DirectLine, Teams, Slack, Facebook, etc.) between your bot and the specific channel. It is also responsible for generating the tokens that allows your bot to connect and pass messages around.

However, it is possible to run your bot without the use of the Azure Bot Service. Two options that *may* serve your needs are:

1. [offline-directline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline): "Unofficial package to emulate the bot framework connector locally."
2. [InDirectLine](https://github.com/newbienewbie/InDirectLine): "[T]he DirectLine is a bridge that connects your bot and your client. This project (InDirectLine) is a custom implementation of my own..."

You will need to research both to identify which, if either, could/would meet your needs. But, in short, both projects allow you to run your bot locally, or seemingly from a hosted remote environment, and connect to it.

Hope of help!